# Missing Dependencies in Eclipse IDE with Flink Quickstart

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, apache-flink

I have cloned [Flink Training repo](https://github.com/dataArtisans/flink-training-exercises.git) and followed instructions on building and deploying from  [here](http://training.data-artisans.com/) in order to get familiar with [Apache Flink](https://flink.apache.org/). However, there are the errors in the projects after building and importing into Eclipse IDE. In the `Flink Training Exercises` project  i find errors in the pom `Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration: net.alchim31.maven:scala-maven-plugin:3.1.4:testCompile`.  There are also errors in the project `flink-quickstart-java` .  Some dependencies are not being resolved e.g. `ExecutionEnvironment cannot be resolved`  in the  `BatchJob` class.

```
public class BatchJob {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    // set up the batch execution environment
    final ExecutionEnvironment env = 
    ExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();
```

I have tried to clean the `.m2` folder and complied/built both projects several times but there is no joy yet ! Generally, I always have issues with Flink dependencies, are there best practices on programming Flink in Java? How can I resolve these dependencies issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got this working in Eclipse by selecting the `add-dependencies-for-IDEA` maven profile.

I added this section to <build> <plugins> in my pom file:

```
<plugin>
   <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
   <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
   <version>1.6.0</version>
   <executions>
     <execution>
       <goals>
        <goal>java</goal>
       </goals>
    </execution>
   </executions>
   <configuration>
      <mainClass>org.apache.flink.flink_quickstart_java.BatchJob</mainClass>
   </configuration>
</plugin>
```

and then created a Maven Build run configuration with

```
Goals: org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:java
Profiles: add-dependencies-for-IDEA
```

Comment: i have tried on eclipse, I have the following error :                            `[INFO] --- exec-maven-plugin:1.6.0:java (default-cli) @ flink-java-project --- [WARNING] java.lang.RuntimeException: No data sinks have been created yet. A program needs at least one sink that consumes data. Examples are writing the data set or printing it. at org.apache.flink.api.java.ExecutionEnvironment.createProgramPlan(ExecutionEnvironment.java:943) at org.apache.flink. .... `

Comment: this answer works in conjunction with other instructions all specified at this [page](http://training.data-artisans.com/devEnvSetup.html).