# Creating Flink Project in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, apache-flink

I'm trying to create a Flink Maven project with eclipse and run some selfwritten codefiles. I used this tutorial: https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.6/quickstart/java_api_quickstart.html
I have done all steps of the tutorial. If I try to run a example file this error message occur:
[image]

Also if I'm trying to generate a new Java class - the error

> Source folder is not a java project.

My goal is to create own Flink applications and test them in the IDE environment.
Thanks in advance

Comment: From the link: `If you use Eclipse, the m2e plugin allows to import Maven projects.` Do you have that plugin?

Comment: Also, I know this is not a proper solution and I don't want to start an IDE battle but... have you considered giving IntelliJ a try? It might save you some headaches :)

Comment: Yes m2e is installed and I imported the quckstart project via import - maven - existing project
actually i don't like IntelliJ but if there is no other solution I will give IntelliJ a try :-/

Comment: Maybe you're selecting the wrong directory when importing the project. You should select the directory containing the `pom.xml`.

Comment: It should be the right project. But I installed IntelliJ and redid the tutorial and now my sample files are running.
So this is an eclipse issue. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I got this to work a while back -- see the [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50622817/2000823).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the errors don't occur with IntelliJ.